# Terraform conditional for AWS route tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Using Terraform, I need to create a route table for a public subnet and private subnet. The resource for a 'public' route table is using `gateway_id`

```
resource "aws_route_table" "rt-public" { 
    route {
        cidr_block = var.cidr_block      
        gateway_id = var.gateway_id
    }
 }
```

The 'private' route table is using `nat_gateway_id`:

```
resource "aws_route_table" "rt-private" { 
    route {
        cidr_block       =  var.cidr_block      
        nat_gateway_id   =  var.gateway_id
    }
 }
```

I pass from the `main.tf` file a variable `var.tier` that indicates whether I need a 'public' or 'private' route table.

I tried the following (in the module):

```
resource "aws_route_table" "rt-public" { 
    count      = var.tier == "Public" ? 1 : 0

    route {
        cidr_block = var.cidr_block      
        gateway_id = var.gateway_id

    }
 } 

resource "aws_route_table" "rt-private" { 
    count      = var.tier == "Private" ? 1 : 0
    route {
        cidr_block      =   var.cidr_block      
        nat_gateway_id  =   var.gateway_id 
    }

 }
```

This works. But in the `main.tf` I also need to access the route table id. So I created an `outputs.tf` file as follows:

```
output "aws_rt_public_id" {
  value = aws_route_table.rt-public.id
}

output "aws_rt_private_id" {
  value = aws_route_table.rt-private.id
}
```

The issue is that when a 'public' route table is created, then the 'private' output is empty. I get the error message: `aws_route_table.rt-private is empty tuple. The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.`

Similar error message for the public version.

How can this be fixed using conditionals?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use your condition, and return only output that is valid:

```
output "aws_rt_public_id" {
  value = var.tier == "Public" ? aws_route_table.rt-public[0].id : null 
}

output "aws_rt_private_id" {
  value = var.tier == "Private" ? aws_route_table.rt-private[0].id : null 
}
```

In the above the `null`, when chosen, will result in a given output removed.

Comment: Thanks. This works with the exeption that I need to add the index. `value = var.p4c-tier == "Public" ? aws_route_table.p4c-rt-public[0].id : null`. If you modify your answer I can accept it.